# font stuck in Wingdings

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

Hello Ubuntu Community,

My son inadvertently changed the computer font to Wingdings and now we cannot figure out how to get back a readable font.  All we see are the symbols.

ANY SUGGESTIONS??

Answer (score 1):

Hit CTRL+ALT+T to open a terminal.

Then type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font 'Ubuntu 10'
```

The `Ubuntu 10` is the font name and default font size.

Hope this helps :-).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it now states No such schema org.gnome.nautilus.desktop

Comment: try it with `gsettings set org.gnome.interface font 'Ubuntu 10'`. Perhaps you could copy-paste the output of `gsettings list-schemas | sort` to the Ubuntu Pastebin. http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Thanks I will try.  I am on a different computer trying to fix the other.

Comment: No such schema org.interface.  I entered gsettings list-schemas and a ton populated.  I am pleading ignorance here and have NO idea what they mean. My brother installed this system on my son's computer and he is out of the country unable to assist.  THANK U for taking the time to help me

Comment: `org.interface` indeed won't exist. `org.gnome.interface` probably will. The `gsettings list-schemas | sort` will indeed output a lot; can you please copy-paste this output to paste.ubuntu.com, so we can have a look at what you have?

Comment: I do not know how to transfer from one computer to another so I will have to enter each one manually.

Comment: OK. I assume you have a usb stick? Plug it into the affected computer. Then type the following in a terminal: `gsettings list-schemas | sort > ~/Desktop/askubuntu.txt`. This will make a text file called askubuntu.txt on your desktop with this information. Then, type `nautilus` in the terminal. This will open the file browser. Then drag and drop the askubuntu.txt file into your usb stick.

Comment: Yes, located the USB however, my son cannot get command prompt on the Ubuntu computer to find this symbol/line:  | .

Comment: It depends on the keyboard layout. But usually located on the same key as the backslash ( \ ) is. Shift-hold that key to get |.

Comment: the info did not successfully transfer to the usb.  I wish I could email you a screen shot from my phone so you can see what   a mess this is

Comment: OK I tried to drag and drop and a new window opened with every symbol under the sun

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your reply, but I have no idea what that means.  I am ignorant when it comes to this.  I clicked learn more and was still confused

Comment: I have retried the previous steps and There is nothing in the usb.  The computer also continues to freeze up Any other suggestions?

Comment: WAIT!!!!  I think it worked and pasted to the Ubuntu Pastebin.  If anyone can help I would GREATLY appreciate it